# Demonstration of linearity property on a Lebesgue space

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, lebesgue-integral

Imagine the Lebesgue space $L^2_\mu(\mathbb{R},\mathbb{C})$, a space of functions $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{C}$, where the measure function is $\mu=\frac{e^{-x^2}}{\sqrt{\pi}}$. If a function $f$ belong to this space then the following condition is satisfied:

$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} |f(x)|^2e^{-x^2}dx<\infty$$

I want to demonstrate that $L^2_{\mu}$ is a vector space. So, it must satisfy the following conditions:

(i) Existence of origin $(0)$, i.e.

$$0\in L^2_{\mu}$$

(ii) Closed for sum of elements, i.e.

$$f,g\in L^2_{\mu}\Rightarrow f+g \in L^2_{\mu}$$

(iii) Closed for multiplication by scalars, i.e.

$$a\in \mathbb{K}, f\in L^2_{\mu} \Rightarrow af\in L^2_{\mu}$$

The (i) and (iii) conditions are easy to demonstrate. My problem is on (ii) condition where I did the following procedure:

$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} |f(x)+g(x)|^2e^{-x^2}dx=\frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \left(f(x)+g(x)\right).\left(f(x)+g(x)\right)^*e^{-x^2}dx=
$$

$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} |f(x)|^2+|g(x)|^2+2\text{Re}\{f(x)g^*(x)\}e^{-x^2}dx$$

I know that $\frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} |f(x)|^2e^{-x^2}dx<\infty$ and $\frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} |g(x)|^2e^{-x^2}dx<\infty$ because $f,g\in L^2_{\mu}$ but I don't know what to with the term $\text{Re}\{f(x)g^*(x)\}$ on this integration.

What would you do?

Comment: $\mid a+b\mid< \mid a\mid +\mid b\mid$

Comment: @TsemoAristide I thought about triangular inequality, but there's a square on the sum which will get a product term. That product it's my only complication

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:** $$|f(x) + g(x)|^2 \le 2|f(x)|^2 + 2|g(x)|^2$$

**Proof of the hint:** $0 \le (a - b)^2 = a^2 + b^2 -2ab$. Rearranging we have $$2ab\le a^2 + b^2. \tag 1$$

Now, as you noticed in the comment below $$|f(x) + g(x)|^2 \le |f(x)|^2 + |g(x)|^2 + 2|f(x)||g(x)|.$$
Apply $(1)$ with $a = |f(x)|$, $b = |g(x)|$ to the last term on the RHS to get the desired result.

Comment: If this proposition is right then it is enough to solve my problem. But how did you get there? Triangular inequality gives you $|f(x)+g(x)|^2\leq|f(x)|^2+|g(x)|^2+2|g(x)|.|f(x)|$...

Comment: @ÉlioPereira Use triangular inequality, then expand $(|f(x)|+|g(x)|)^2$ and use the fact that $2|f(x)||g(x)|\leq |f(x)|^2+|g(x)|^2$. That should do it.

Comment: I get it! By the parallelogram equality we have:
$|f+g|^2+|f-g|^2=2|f|^2+2|g|^2\Leftrightarrow |f+g|^2=2|f|^2+2|g|^2-|f-g|^2$. So, $|f+g|^2\leq2|f|^2+2|g|^2$

Comment: @ÉlioPereira: I have edited to include the proof, but it seems you have already figured it out, well done! ;)